# ocaml using tuareg interactively

Tags: ocaml

Why do I get the following when running ocaml interactively under tuareg 2.05?

```
    OCaml version 4.01.0
```

Cannot find file topfind.
Unknown directive `camlp4o'.

I'm using OSX 10.9.

Iain

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a `.ocamlinit` that tries to load topfind, which is failing because you do not have the right directory in the search path.

If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say that you've put some configuration junk (maybe something like `` eval `opam config env` ``) in a configuration file such as `~/.bashrc` that arranges for this to work in the shell, but emacs doesn't get to see it because `.bashrc` is not consulted by the desktop environment in which you start emacs. Does running ocaml under bash in the same directory work and successfully load topfind? If so, find which configuration files your environment does consult and move the relevant code into one of those. `~/.profile`, maybe.